# Laravel Auth::attempt fails

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a login system for admin users, but the Auth::attempt returns false...
Is there anyone that can help me with this? :p I've followed the documentation from four.laravel.com, but I can't seem to get to a solution...

### AdminController@auth

```
public function auth()
{

    $rules = [
        'email'    => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $credentials = [
            'email'      => Input::get('email'),
            'password'   => Input::get('password'),
            'deleted_at' => null, // Extra voorwaarde
        ];

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return Redirect::to('/');
        } else {
            return Redirect::route('admin.login')
                ->withInput()
                ->with('auth-error-message', 'U heeft een onjuiste gebruikersnaam of een onjuist wachtwoord ingevoerd.');
        }
    } else {

        return Redirect::route('admin.login') // Zie: $ php artisan routes
            ->withInput()             // Vul het formulier opnieuw in met de Input.
            ->withErrors($validator); // Maakt $errors in View.
    }
}
```

### Admin Model

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Admin extends Eloquent {
protected $table = 'admins';
    protected $softDelete = true;

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'password'
    ];


    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'email',
        'approved'
    ];
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function ($admin) {
            $admin->password = Hash::make($admin->password);
        });
    }

}
```

### Admin Migration

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('admins', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email','255')->unique();
        $table->string('password','60');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamp('approved')->nullable();
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.
HS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've figured it out myself eventually.
I had changed the name of the default user class to 'Admin'. Since laravel automatically implements the UserInterface to the User-model, I needed to manually implement it in the Admin-model:

```
class Admin extends Eloquent implements UserInterface{
{
    ...
}
```

That's all that was to it..

Answer (score 1):

Does your `auth.php` configuration file match your different model/table structure?

```
'model' => 'Admin';
'table' => 'admins';
```

Also you do not have `protected $softDelete = true;` within your admin model yet you are checking against it with your `Auth::attempt();`. See http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting.

Comment: I had configured the auth.php file and I tried to add the $softDelete = true; but it didn't make any difference. :s i've also added the migration in my question.. maybe that's worth something..

Comment: Have you tried removing the `deleted_at` from the credentials? I think Laravel performs this check anyway for you. Does the validation pass?

Comment: validation passes. I get the auth-error-message when I try to log in..  and the deleted_at-thingy doesn't do the trick either.. :s

Comment: Try manually comparing the hashed password in the database http://laravel.com/docs/security#storing-passwords (copy it out) against the POST'ed password value. If they don't match then there's your issue. Also try debugging as you run through it etc `var_dump(Request::all());`

Comment: well I've tried to manually compare the passwords and they don't match.. but how's that possible? I hash both passwords with the Hash::make(); function... ?

Comment: Try restoring the new password hash in the table instead and then compare, I don't know if Laravel takes the application key into account or not as that could of affected it.

Comment: I'm one step further now. I manage to check the two passwords with the Auth::check() function. However, when I try to log the user in manually through the Auth::loginUsingId() function, I get following error: 'Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, instance of Admin given'